# react-leaflet-rotatedmarkers: TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

as you can see in the topic is my problem that when i want to import react-leaflet-rotatedmarker, only importing, my react webapplication throws me this message.

I'm using react-leaflet v2.1.2.

Here is a snippet of my js code:

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Map, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import L, { map, addTo } from 'leaflet';
import RotatedMarker from 'react-leaflet-rotatedmarker'
import './App.css'

//importing marker/icon
var ego_veh_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: require('./design/icons/ego_veh_arrow.svg'),
    iconSize: [150, 200],
    iconAnchor: [82.5, 40],
    popupAnchor: [0, -25],
});

var av_veh_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: require('./design/icons/autonom_veh_arrow.svg'),
    iconSize: [150, 200],
    iconAnchor: [82.5,55],
    popupAnchor: [-5, -25],
});

var nav_veh_icon = L.icon({
    iconUrl: require('./design/icons/non_autonom_veh_arrow.svg'),
    iconSize: [150, 200],
    iconAnchor: [82.5, 60],
    popupAnchor: [-10, -25],
});

class Map_hmi extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {
            markers: [[x, y]],
            param: null,
        };
    }

    // ego veh position 
    ego_veh = {
        lat: x,
        lng: y,
    }

     // nav veh position 
     nav_veh = {
        lat: x,
        lng: y,
    }

     // av veh1 position 
     av_veh1 = {
        lat: x,
        lng: y,
    }

    // av veh2 position 
    av_veh2 = {
        lat: x
        lng: y,
    }

    render() {
        
        const ego_veh_pos = [this.ego_veh.lat, this.ego_veh.lng]
        const nav_veh_pos = [this.nav_veh.lat, this.nav_veh.lng]
        const av_veh1_pos = [this.av_veh1.lat, this.av_veh1.lng]
        const av_veh2_pos = [this.av_veh2.lat, this.av_veh2.lng]
        return (
            // declaring the map
            <Map
                className="map"
                center={ego_veh_pos}
                zoom={15}
                zoomControl={false}
            >
                <TileLayer
                    attribution='&amp;copy <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                />  
                    {/* <RotatedMarker position={position} rotationAngle={180} rotationOrigin={'center'} /> */}
                    {/* ego veh */}
                    <Marker 
                        position={ego_veh_pos}
                        icon= {ego_veh_icon}>
                        <Popup>
                        EGO <br/>
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    {/* nav veh */}
                    <Marker 
                        position={nav_veh_pos}
                        icon= {nav_veh_icon}>
                        <Popup>
                        NAV <br/>
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                    {/* av veh1 */}
                    <Marker 
                        position={av_veh1_pos}
                        icon= {av_veh_icon}>
                        <Popup>
                        AV <br/>
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                     {/* av veh2 */}
                     <Marker 
                        position={av_veh2_pos}
                        icon= {av_veh_icon}>
                        <Popup>
                        AV <br/>
                        </Popup>
                    </Marker>
                )}
            </Map>
            
        );
    }
}

export default Map_hmi;
```

So my code works fine without the import, but as soon as I import it:

> > TypeError: Super expression must either be null or a function, not object

I only want to rotate the icon ....

Any help?

Greetings

Comment: Have you tried to remove the semicolon after the super().

Comment: yes, not working either

Comment: Define state in same way as `ego_veh` outside constructor and remove constructor completly.

Comment: Are you sure this error is thrown for this `super`, not somwhere else?

Comment: ok so, it's another solution. it was the react-leaflet version. now i'm on 1.7.8 . maybe it's useful for other people aswell. v2 and higher is not working. but thanks you all!

Answer (score 2):

[The provided another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53781059/1375553) seems to be correct, [`react-leaflet-rotatedmarker` package](https://github.com/verdie-g/react-leaflet-rotatedmarker) is not compatible with `react-leaflet v2` package.

For `react-leaflet v2` library, `RotatedMarker` component could be implemented like this (*offers same behavior as `react-leaflet-rotatedmarker` package*):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { withLeaflet } from "react-leaflet";
import { Marker } from "react-leaflet";
import { Marker as LeafletMarker } from 'leaflet-rotatedmarker';

const RotatedMarker = props => {
  const setupMarker = marker => {
    if (marker) {
      if (props.rotationAngle)
        marker.leafletElement.setRotationAngle(props.rotationAngle);
      marker.leafletElement.setRotationOrigin(props.rotationOrigin);
    }
  };

  return <Marker ref={el => setupMarker(el)} {...props} />;
};

RotatedMarker.defaultProps = {
  rotationOrigin: "center"
};

export default withLeaflet(RotatedMarker);
```

[Demo page](https://codesandbox.io/s/732jk4m4rx)

Answer (score 1):

tldr: Using the code in this comment should fix your problem. https://github.com/verdie-g/react-leaflet-rotatedmarker/issues/1#issuecomment-427285940

Longer answer:
`react-leaflet` v2 has a very major breaking change from v1 in the way extensions of components are done. If you look at the code for `react-leaflet-rotatedmarker` you'll see this line: https://github.com/verdie-g/react-leaflet-rotatedmarker/blob/master/src/RotatedMarker.jsx#L5

That extension of the `Marker` class does not work in v2 and is what's throwing that error. For more info on why that is you can check out the issue I raised in the `react-leaflet` repo. https://github.com/PaulLeCam/react-leaflet/issues/506